# C++: Why I can't pass a pair of iterators to regex_search?

Tags: c++

I try to pass a pair of iterators to represent a string sequence:

```
    #include<regex>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        smatch results;
        string temp("abc");
        string test("abc");

        regex r(temp);
        auto iter = test.begin();
        auto end = test.end();

        if(regex_search(iter,end,results,r))
    cout<<results.str()<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The error goes like:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&, std::smatch&, std::regex&)’
>     if(regex_search(iter,end,results,r))

Comment: try changing values of iter and end from test.begin() and test.end() to `test.cbegin()` and `test.cend()`

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having here is a type mismatch between the iterators you are passing to `regex_search` and the iterator defined for `smatch`.  `std::smatch` is defined as:

```
typedef match_results<string::const_iterator> smatch;
```

and `iter` and `end` have the type of

```
string::iterator
```

When you call [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) the iterator version is defined as

> ```
> template< class BidirIt, 
>         class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits >  
> bool regex_search( BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
>                    std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc>& m,
>                    const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& e,
>                    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = 
>                        std::regex_constants::match_default );
> ```

And as we can see the iterators and the iterators of the `match_result` have to match.  If we change

```
auto iter = test.begin();
auto end = test.end();
```

To

```
auto iter = test.cbegin();
auto end = test.cend();
```

Then everything now has the type of `string::const_iterator` and it will compile

```
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    smatch results;
    string temp("abc");
    string test("abc");

    regex r(temp);
    auto iter = test.cbegin();
    auto end = test.cend();

    if (regex_search(iter, end, results, r))
        cout << results.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd8afefa1ff14e04)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`regex_search` expects a `const_iterator` but you are passing a `std::string::iterator`.

---

Make your string `const`

```
const string test("abc");
```

Declare a `const_iterator`

```
std::string::const_iterator iter = test.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = test.end();
```

Or use `cbegin` and `cend`

```
auto iter = test.cbegin();
auto end = test.cend();
```