# std::regex_search override with parameter of range doesn't compile

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

I want to use this override of [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) which can assgin offset (range) of the target string.

```
template< class BidirIt,
          class CharT, class Traits >
bool regex_search( BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
                   const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& e,
                   std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = 
                       std::regex_constants::match_default );
```

Below is my code which doesn't compile. Getting rid of the m parameter would make it work, but I can retrieve the match information as that.

```
string s = "a**b cd e*f.";
size_t asteriskPos = s.find('*');
std::smatch m;
bool b = std::regex_search(s.begin()+asteriskPos , s.end(), m, std::regex("[^a-z*]"));
cout << b << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

I find this [C++: Why I can't pass a pair of iterators to regex_search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307440/c-why-i-cant-pass-a-pair-of-iterators-to-regex-search)

```
auto iter = test.cbegin();
auto end = test.cend();
```

Const iterator would work.