# std::regex_search reverse search

Tags: c++, regex, string, iterator, c++17

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307828/9250490
You can find the first 5-sequential-number `12345` via `regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend()...`

```
string s = "abcde, eee12345 11111ddd 55555 hello";
std::smatch m;
bool b = std::regex_search(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), m, std::regex("[0-9]{5}"));
cout << m[0] << endl;
```

But if I want to find the last `55555`, I tried,

```
std::regex_search(s.crbegin(), s.crend(), m, std::regex("[0-9]{5}"));
```

But it doesn't compile with error,

`Error  C2672   'std::regex_search': no matching overloaded function found  ForTest`

on Visual Studion 2019 with C++17 standard.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the iterator types do not match, if you look at the source of `std::smatch` in Visual Studio you'll find this.

```cpp
using smatch  = match_results<string::const_iterator>;
```

And you're trying to pass `std::string::const_reverse_iterator` in your `std::regex_search` call.

Use `std::match_results<std::string::const_reverse_iterator>` directly instead.

```cpp
const std::string s = "abcde, eee12345 11111ddd 55555 hello";
std::match_results<std::string::const_reverse_iterator> m;
bool b = std::regex_search(s.crbegin(), s.crend(), m, std::regex("[0-9]{5}"));
std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
```

Comment: As a side note, you should try a different implementation then `std::regex`, which leaves a lot to be desired in terms of performance. For example compile-time regular expressions that you can use with c++17/20 that you can find here https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions